# Leads to implement cart in shopping cart using Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

---

I have implemented shopping cart up to product. But have no idea on how to implement separate cart for each user.

## Please share your ideas

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187799/404-error-in-associate-mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share your effort / code along with your question always.

According to me this can go with many scenarios

One of the scenarios would be like,

User have One Cart, Cart will have many products and many Products belongs to many carts

Code goes as below, You can go ahead and add required parameters to the entity.

**User Entity**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Cart cart;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Cart getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(Cart cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }

}
```

**Cart Entity**

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CART")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CART_PRODUCT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CART_ID") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID") )
    private Set<Product> products;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

**Product Entity**

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String productName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "products")
    private Set<Cart> carts;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Set<Cart> getCarts() {
        return carts;
    }

    public void setCarts(Set<Cart> carts) {
        this.carts = carts;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tq for consider my qs...Got the same idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217992/how-to-retrive-logged-in-user-data-in-spring-mvc-and-hibernate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217992/how-to-retrive-logged-in-user-data-in-spring-mvc-and-hibernate