# How to retrive logged in user data in spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to get current loggedin user's details along entertain session.Is there any poissible to do it in `Spring` and `hibernate`

I am new to spring and hibernate...Help me guys.

Comment: you can inject a `Principal` object in a Controller

Comment: `Customer c = (Customer)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();String name=c.getEmail();` is it fine???

Comment: you can also cast the injected principal to your Customer c

Comment: One more doubt whether it retrive all data like first name,last name,,etc..or  Only username ????

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral ways in which you can accomplish this.  In a controller you can inject a `Pricipal` as a parameter.

```
@RequestMapping()
public void getPricipal(Principal principal) {
   Customer c = (Customer) pricipal;
}
```

You should also be able to inject the `UserDetails` directly as well. Spring will resolve it for you.  Your `Customer` class must implement UserDetails

```
@RequestMapping()
public void getPricipal(Customer customer) {

}
```

---

As for having all details,  you should be able to access the firstname, lastname etc, if you've implemented your own `UserDetailsService` where you return your custom `UserDetails` (`Customer`).